# Wordpress Fusion Core Plugin working on Custom Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress

So I want to include fusion builder's post editor on some custom post types that I've created. There is a fix to this go to fusion-core > admin > class-pagebuilder.php and edit line 53.

```
var $allowed_post_types = array('page','post','avada_faq','avada_portfolio', 'add my custom types here');
```

But anytime there is an update this will be deleted and I'd like to not have to worry about this, or worry about it! So is there anyway i can create a plugin helper, or add something to my functions.php file that wont get replaced every time there is an update.

Answer (score 1):

the instance is create line 22 of the file fusion-core.php

so to overide this, you can try something like this :

```
add_action ("plugins_loaded", function () {

    // unregister habitual call
    remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Fusion_Core_PageBuilder', 'get_instance' ) );

    // call of the instance
    // you have to change the path of the fusion-core plugin

    if( ! get_option( 'avada_disable_builder' ) ) {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            require_once( path of the fusion-core plugin . 'admin/class-pagebuilder.php' );

            $instance = Fusion_Core_PageBuilder::get_instance();
            $instance->allowed_post_types[] = "custom post type";
        }
    }

}, 9); // priority 9 to be called before the line of fusion-core.php
```

Comment: how does the path to the plugin work? relative to the functions.php file? i've tried "../../plugins/fusion-core/" and i've tired "wp-content/plugins/fusion-core/"

Comment: try that : `require_once(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../fusion-core/admin/class-pagebuilder.php' );`

Comment: Do i have to replace __FILE__ with something, please excuse the dumb question

Comment: At the top of the class-pagebuilder.php file there is this line : `define ('FUSION_BUILDER_PATH' ,  plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) );`

Comment: The constructor for `Fusion_Core_PageBuilder` creates an instance of `Fusion_Core_PageBuilder_UI` like this: `require_once( 'page-builder/classes/class-ui.php' ); $settings['allowed_post_types'] = $this->allowed_post_types; $instances['ui'] = Fusion_Core_PageBuilder_UI::get_instance( $settings );` which means that you need to change that class' instance settings too in addition to doing the above. Add this in the inner `if` block: `$ui = Fusion_Core_PageBuilder_UI::get_instance(); $ui->settings['allowed_post_types'][] = 'custom post type';` - HTH

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that there was no need to remove the action...and in fact, it did not work when I did so.  Instead, I simply called the same action and changed the values.  I also found that I only needed the "UI instance".  Here's what worked for me.  I've now added the page builder successfully to ten different post types on my site see below:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    require_once('path to plugin directory/fusion-core/admin/class-pagebuilder.php' );
    require_once('path to plugin directory/fusion-core/admin/page-builder/classes/class-ui.php' );

    $ui = Fusion_Core_PageBuilder_UI::get_instance();
    $ui->settings['allowed_post_types'][] = 'your_custom_post_type';

}
```

Comment: In my case, it's within a plugin file, but yes you could add this to functions.php.

You will need to replace the above values however, which are only for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: FYI, this is now outdated.